# Date formatting with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I'm passing a simple object into my RABL view, the rabl view is basically two lines:

```
object @invitations
attributes :email, :active, :invitation_sent_at, :invitation_accepted_at
```

How can I format the date `:invitation_sent_at`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the formatted attribute as a node:

```
object @invitations
attributes :email, :active
node(:formatted_invitation_sent_at){|invite| invite.invitation_sent_at.strftime(some_format)}
node(:formatted_invitation_accepted_at){|invite| invite.invitation_accepted_at.strftime(some_format)}
```

Alternatively, make this a helper_method in your model, and pass that helper_method instead of the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting on the client might be better.

If you use something like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), the following should work.

```
<ul ng-repeat="invitation in invitations">

  <li>{{ invitation.invitation_sent_at | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. I actually am using angular and was unaware of these kinds of formatting capabilities, might use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you may want to format the date in the application receiving the response rather than in the response itself. This will keep your RABL templates decoupled from the final rendering of the date and thus more easily consumable.

Then assuming you're consuming the response with JavaScript:

```
// parse manually
var invitedAt = new Date(response.invitation_sent_at); // assumes Rails default UTC formatting
invitedAt.getFullYear(); // 2014
invitedAt.getMonth(); // 1
// etc.

// parse with a library like moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)
moment(response.invitation_sent_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 12th 2014, 1:01:59 pm
```

Comment: yeah, it's just so much more of a hassle doing this in javascript than just '.strftime()'. Good point about keeping the api 'more consumable' though, that's probably the best reason I should keep the formatting client-side, regardless of the hassle.